# Выбрать модификацию с минимальной ценой

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица со списком товаров, для простоты представим её так:

```
ТАБЛИЦА: goods
--------------
id      name
1       name1
2       name2
3       name3
```

Вторая таблица, это модификации товаров:

```
ТАБЛИЦА: mod
------------
id     id_goods  price  mod
1      1         100    red
2      1         200    white
3      2         50     red
```

После запроса

```
SELECT gd.*, md.price
FROM goods AS gd 
LEFT JOIN mod as md
ON gd.id = md.id_goods
```

получается что-то вроде этого

```
id  name   price
1   name1  100
1   name1  200
2   name2  50
3   name3  NULL
```

а нужно как-то оставить только модификации с МИНИМАЛЬНОЙ ценой, но что бы товары присутствовали ВСЕ. То есть как-то так:

```
id  name   price
1   name1  100
2   name2  50
3   name3  NULL
```

Я не сильно владею mysql, это вообще реальная задача?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT gd.*, min(md.price)
FROM `goods` AS gd 
LEFT JOIN `mod` as md
ON gd.id = md.id_goods 
GROUP BY gd.id
```

P.S. не называйте таблицы зарезервированными именами (mod, order и т.д.)

Comment: min(md.price) я делал, а GROUP BY не додумался, спасибо!